# SPARQL query fails

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web

I am using jena to make SPARQL query over the Yago vocabulary. I use a loop with a set of elements that replace the SPARQL. So for example I have a file from which I get the class names. It looks like this:

```
wordnet_aircraft_102686568
wordnet_airline_102690081
wordnet_airport_102692232
wordnet_album_106591815
wordnet_ambassador_109787534
wikicategory_American_football_leagues_in_the_United_States
wikicategory_National_Football_League_teams
wordnet_amphibian_102704792
wordnet_body_part_105220461
```

The SPARQL generated looks like:

```
    SELECT  ?entity
    WHERE
    { ?entity rdf:type <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wordnet_album_106591815> }
```

The query runs fine for 3 or 4 elements, but then it blocks at `wordnet_album_106591815` and it returns an `HttpException: 500` .

I deleted that value from the file, and the query went forward for a few more elements and then got stuck again.

I copied the query to a SPARQL endpoint (http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql), it works sometimes, but sometimes I get `Error S1T00 SR171: Transaction timed out`

What are the possible reasons behind this behavior?

Comment: You haven't provided us enough information to diagnose anything.  E.g., *where* are you running the original query? What's the data you're querying?  Maybe there are just lots of resources of that type.  If you change your query to `select … where { … } limit 100`, do things work any better?  Does anything change if you start with that particular query?  Maybe you're getting rate limited by a server.  Without more information, it's rather hard to say.

Comment: "HttpException: 500" means the server has failed your query (look in the HttpException - it will have details if the server provides any).   jena merely reports what the far end says - that is where your query is failing.

Comment: I edited my code with the function where it fails.

Comment: Again, pointing you towards the response by @AndyS, a [HTTP 5XX Server Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a response from the server that indicates that, according to the server, there was an error _inside the server_. The lack of a 4XX usually indicates that the client made the request correctly. Your query looks perfectly fine for what I can tell. If you want to verify for yourself, download the dataset and run the query locally inside Jena.

Comment: I strongly believe that it is the server's fault. Even trying to access the sparql URL results in in that timeout error!

Comment: @user1350162 OK, if it's the server's fault, what do you hope to be able to do differently to avoid the problem?  Your code can't make someone else's server more reliable, can it?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, unfortunately not! and the problem is that I am doing all this for my Masters thesis and every time I keep getting stuck because of the server being down! Is there anything to propose other than downloading the whole dataset? I am using a 4GB RAM pc, I dont think it will be sufficient to support such a big data. I was thinking about running the queries for the classes and storing the results in files, so I will end up with a huge number of text files, but if it is the only solution you can suggest, I would go for it.

Comment: I don't know how big the dataset is; you haven't told us exactly what it is.  The amount of RAM *might* not be quite so important though.  I don't know much about Virtuoso, but I know that Jena has TDB which stores the triples indexed on disk, and queries efficiently there.  I assume that Virtuoso has something like that.  You might be surprised at how quickly the queries can run locally.

Comment: I actually need mainly to get all instance of all classes alongside with the sameAs links of these instances, and superclass/subclass hierarchies. which datasets am I supposed to download? 

Is there some tutorial out there on how to use the Yago/Geonames datasets with Jena? Do I need virtuoso to be able to query locally?